# Alternative or new Jakarta Faces 4.0 Components

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, mojarra

As a longtime JBoss/Wildly user with 'Mojarra'. I always used JSF 'RichFaces'. Due to end-of-life in June 2016 I migrated to PrimeFaces.

The main/only five 'extra' PF components I use are:

- dataTable
- graphicImage
- tabView & tab
- ajax event="tabChange" (ERROR)
- galleria (ERROR)

'dataTable' has been perfect and 'graphicImage'.

I'm unable to get 'galleria' to run with 'dynamic data' and 'tabChange' has never worked ever. RichFaces 'tabChange' always worked.

I've invested too much effort & time into JSF so want to continue using **Jakarta Faces 4.0**.

I've Google'd again through RichFaces, IceFaces, ADF, MyFaces etc. and look I'm stuck with PF.

Anyone aware of any new or test version of 'Faces' components that have the five components I primarily use elsewhere?

(2)

Have created a simple/basic PF 12.4/13.0.0-RC2 Demo. Exactly as the PF 'Demo'. Just of 'TabView' deployed on **WildFy 29.0.0.Beta1** using **Mojarra 4.0.2**. EAR = JAR + WAR.

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/tabView.xhtml?jfwid=5e8fa

When I select any of the three 'tabs' I get:

```
SEVERE [jakarta.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.faces.context] (default task-4) jakarta.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @57,101 listener="#{tabbedView.onTabChange}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'tabbedView' resolved to null: jakarta.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @57,101 listener="#{tabbedView.onTabChange}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'tabbedView' resolved to null
```

(3)

Had enough with 'PrimeFaces'. Will be moving all to Kotlin Multi Platform:

https://kotlinlang.org/lp/multiplatform/

Comment: I don't see your point of trying to find other components. Instead it would be more helpful if you could provide runnable reproducers (https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test) showing the issues you are having. There is a dynamic galleria example in the documentation, and the `tabChange` event works (I use it all the time).

Comment: Not if using Mojarra 4.0.0.SP01, EE (WildFly 27.x) with Jakaka Faces 4.0. Like for example 'graphicImage' works, but not 'galleria'.  The 'Test' are all on Jetty & mojarra23.

Comment: They are not, and you can modify them to your needs https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test/tree/jakarta

Comment: But, if you've found a bug, please report it and please include a runnable reproducer.

Answer (score -3):

The namespace transaction... is aggravating to say the least. Faced with the same problem, ,I believe Tomitribe at one point had a JVM Agent that would dynamically translate your code; you may check their GitHub page.

In the mean time, BootsFaces will probably do what you want, but it is not under active development. https://showcase.bootsfaces.de

Another is http://tobago-demo.apache.org which is under current development

Comment: Look like both BootFaces & Tobago 5 don't support Jakarta 4.0 Faces. Only JSF 2.3. No support of a  PF 'galleria' either. TIA.

Comment: Apologies, I thought you were wanting to _not_ upgrade to Faces4.0. I read your question incorrectly.